# iOS / Core Data: How to create a predicate for words that start with a range of characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

The 'Like' is pretty simple it seems, it only supports ? and * I believe, kind of like old-school wildcards.

But I want to do this: Find all words that begin with a given range of characters... for example a-j.

So I got it to find all words that start with say, the letter j:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name LIKE 'j*'"];
```

However, I can't figure out how to match all words that begin with a certain range, for example a-j:
"Name LIKE '[a-j]*'" doesn't work..

any ideas how I might achieve this? Or will my only way be to do something like:
"Name LIKE 'a*' OR Name LIKE 'b*' OR Name LIKE 'c*' OR Name LIKE 'd*' ... " cause that would be unfortunate...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MATCHES`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) will let you use regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

Example & for easy copypasta:

```
//title starts with number
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title MATCHES '^[0-9].*'"];

//title starts with letter a-j or A-J
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title MATCHES '^[a-jA-J].*'"];
```

Answer (score 1):

**MATCHES works for arrays of Core Data objects only!!!**

For example, you can't use it for request to sqlite database to get these arrays or you will get the following exception:

```
Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (SELF MATCHES ...
```